# Performance counter files in Windows Server 2016 are limited to 2 GB in size

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

We want to record performance counters in files up to 6 GB in size. This worked on Windows Server 2008 R2 but on Windows Server 2016 the recording stops when the file has reached in 2 GB in size.

We haven't found anything about this limit in the Windows documentation. We are analyzing the files using PAL so we do not want to split them up.

Does anyone know how to get around the 2 GB limit?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are writing the files to a drive that supports files larger than 2 GB.

Comment: How should he do that?

Comment: Thank you for the tips. However I was able to create a file 4 GB in size on the disk by doing a copy. The drive is formatted for NTFS.